# Regex specific repeating interval parser, mostly working

Tags: regex, powershell

I have the following regex:

```
once|every (?:(?:([1-9][0-9]?[0-9]? )?(hours?|days?))|(?:(?:(?:(1st|2nd|3rd|4th|5th))? ?(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)?)|((?:[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])(?:st|nd|rd|th))) ?(?:(of the month)? ?(?:(?:repeated every )([2-9][0-9]?[0-9]?) (weeks|months))?)?)
```

That works for most of what I need, but doesn't for the following string...

```
Every 20th of the month
```

The following work great...

```
Once
Every hour
Every day
Every 2 hours
Every 2 days
Every Monday
Every 1st of the month
Every 1st of the month repeated every 3 months
Every 2nd Monday of the month
Every 2nd Monday of the month repeated every 3 months
```

Can you help?
Thanks

Comment: Are these strings standalone? Not inside bigger text? Try `^(?:<your_pattern_here>)$` then.

Comment: Another idea: make the part matching days of week obligatory, remove `?` after `sunday)`

Comment: It was the missing $ at the end of the entire thing that worked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is with the `(?:(?:(1st|2nd|3rd|4th|5th))? ?(monday|tuesday|wednesday|thursday|friday|saturday|sunday)?)` part: it may match an empty string. Hence, it always "wins".

You may fix it by removing `?` quantifier after `sunday)` to make the day of week an obligatory pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Mtg6/1).

Else, if the strings you check with the regex are standalone, you may enclose the whole pattern with `^(?:` and `)$` patterns to make them match entire pattern. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Y0Mtg6/2).

Comment: Thanks, it was the missing $ at the end of the entire thing that worked.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it is overkill, but I think if you replaced this part of your regex:

```
(1st|2nd|3rd|4th|5th)
```

By something like this:

```
(([1-9]?([2-90](((1st)|(2nd)|(3rd)|([4-90]th))|(1[0-9]th))))|((1st)|(2nd)|(3rd)|([4-9]th)))
```

...you might achieve the desired matching pattern. My idea here was covering any ordinal from 1st to 999th.

**Please notice I haven't this regex tested**, so perhaps it might need some corrections.

---

Also, consider what @Wictor answered: if you are searching these patterns over multiple strings instead of a single multi-string (in other words, all the strings you will check would be like the one in the example, as is, without any other char before and after), wrapping your regexp between `^` and `$` will help making the regex more accurate.

And, as @Wictor said in his answer, if some subpattern accepts empty string as a match, it might behave unexpectedly. Exhaustive trial-and-error might help to find these kind of defficiencies, in order to correct them.

Comment: After reviewing the original regex once again, **I think I overdid it**. There's a pattern more to the right from the subpattern I picked, that looks like it does something similar to what I was trying to cover.

Comment: I couldn't test it anyway... test101.com always gives me `timeout` (even with @Wictor's linked tests). I am using my mobile phone for posting anyway... beside, I don't use PowerShell (I use Linux as my main OS in my PC), so I didn't think I could test the regex in the same flavour than PowerShell anyway... **Even so**, my untested regex manifests an intent. So, I thought it might be helpful somehow... of course, having it tested beforehand is better for an answer, I just did what I could...